# How to include meta description in HTML

Tags: html, meta-tags

What do I need to download so that I can add meta viewport tag in my HTML offline?

I have downloaded bootstrap files and was working with that and then I Googled how to add responsiveness so I found the meta viewport tag. I added it to my code and then wrote some media queries, but when I ran it didn't work.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: i got it now thanks

Comment: Trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar; layout.

Comment: Sorry what's that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use just his:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Not working, i'm using sublime. Don't we have to download some files like in case of bootstrap where we either use the CDN or download & use the file locally.

Comment: @AshishSangwan I don't think so. Are you sure you are attaching this in head in HTML file?

Comment: Yes in the head but where does the media query go in the CSS or the html

Comment: @AshishSangwan CSS